# Javascript animation with variable speed based on cursors position

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

What I want to achieve is a javascript animation with variable speed based on cursor position.

For that porpouse I'm using jquery's animate function and mousever event and javascript's setInterval function, but those aren't required, so if there is a better way to achieve it I would be more than happy to hear it (the only requeriment would be javascript).

The problem I'm facing is that I can't change speed dinamicly, for some reason the speed keeps adding to the one it already had instead of set what I wanted and even if it would change as spected it just doesn't happen in a smoothly way because of an unknown reason for me.

Here is the javascript that I have so far:

```
//settings for container_slider. Are used in startSlider() which handles the animation
var steps_animation_speed = 1000;
var steps_interval = 1500;
var steps_speed_factor = 1;     // 100%
var amount_sliders = 3;

//cache DOM elements
var $container_slider = $('#container_slider');
var $shown_slides = $('.shown_slides', $container_slider);
var $slide = $(".slide");

// Just making sure sizing (widths) fits as they should.
var slides_width = $container_slider.width()/amount_sliders;
var slides_margin = parseInt($slide.css('marginLeft').replace('px', '')) + parseInt($slide.css('marginRight').replace('px', ''));
var steps_width = slides_width + slides_margin;
$shown_slides.css('width', steps_width*(amount_sliders+1) + 'px');
$slide.css('width', slides_width);

var interval;

// This function is responsible of the animation
function startSlider() {
    $shown_slides.stop(false);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        $shown_slides.animate({'margin-left': '-='+steps_width}, steps_animation_speed*steps_speed_factor, function() {
            $('.shown_slides > li:last').after($('.shown_slides > li:first'));
            $('.shown_slides').css('margin-left', '0');
        });
    }, steps_interval);   
}

function pauseSlider() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}

$container_slider.mouseleave(function(){
    steps_interval = 3000;
    $shown_slides.stop(true);
    pauseSlider();
    startSlider();
});

// $container_slider.mouseenter(function(){
//  pauseSlider();
// });

$container_slider.mousemove(function(event){
    pauseSlider();
    var cursor_location = '';
    if(event.pageX > 0 && event.pageX < 165){
        cursor_location = "Cursor is on the left side";
        // This is where i'm doing the tests that should work of changing animation's speed based on cursor position
        if(steps_speed_factor !== (event.pageX / 165)){
            steps_speed_factor = event.pageX / 165;
            steps_speed_factor = (steps_speed_factor < 0.15 ? 0.15 : steps_speed_factor);
            steps_interval = 0;
            startSlider();
        }
    } else if(event.pageX > 165 && event.pageX < ($container_slider.width()-165)){
        cursor_location = "Cursor is in the center (paused)";
        // This stops animation, it could be achieved way better but i'm focusing on above's block of code.
        steps_speed_factor = 1;
        steps_interval = 3000;
        $shown_slides.stop(true);
        pauseSlider();
    } else if(event.pageX > ($container_slider.width()-165) && event.pageX < $container_slider.width()) {
        cursor_location = "Cursor is on the right side";
        // This would be an exact copy (almost) of the left side, but since it doesn't work yet, this is pretty  much a "blank" block of code
        steps_interval = 0;
        steps_speed_factor = ( event.pageX - ($container_slider.width() - 165) ) / 165;
    } 
    $(".coordinates").html("X: " + event.pageX + " Y: " + event.pageY );
    $(".cursor_location").html(cursor_location);
    $(".speed_factor").html("Speed Factor is: "+steps_speed_factor);
});

startSlider();
```

[Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNYoNL) showing this javascript code "working".

--- EDIT

I forgot to explain propperly what happens in the codepen , since it is just an example didnt give it to much importance. Mainly what should happen is that the furthier the cursor is from the center, the tinier/faster the invervals of the animation should be without losing fluidness.

In this case i'm using a "speed factor" which I calculate by taking cursor's X position and then comparing it with a predefined area, converting it in a percentage (decimal) from 15% to 99%. But it isn't actually the important part. I'm clueless about how to achieve this and the more I try the messier my code gets, so as long as you can give me an example of changing animation's speed (in "real" time, i mean, smoothly/fluid) based on cursor's position as an example it would be perfect.

Comment: Do you want the blocks to start and stop like that? Or should the movement be continous?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explaint it correctly (wiill edit it). What I want is, the animation to occur in tinier intervals based onthe distant between the cursor and the center. The furthier from the center the higher that the factor is and the faster the intervals should be. And yes i want it to happen with a continous movement.